# Creating Custom "new" LIST button for custom object

Tags: custom-object, custom-button, button, list-button

I have a junction object called relationships. It is tied to Projects and Accounts. I am just trying to create a custom list button that adds a new record.

So far I have this:
window.open("{!URLFOR($Action.Relationship__c.New)}");

Settings are on execute javascript but I tried all the other settings too. It always leads to a broken page. Have tried many variations--anyone have any advice on how to simply create a new record? The reason I do not want to use the original "New Relationship" button is because I want to change the label to something more custom "New Account" on the project object, and "New Project" on the account object.

thanks!

Comment: Answer: 1. Behaviour : Display in existing window without sidebar and header 2. Content Source : URL 3. Code: {!URLFOR($Action.Relationship__c.New,null)};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the URL for parameter requires two inputs, the Action, and the ID for the record.

When I do what you have I get a JS error. However when I do this I get the correct URL:

```
window.open("{!URLFOR($Action.Relationship__c.New,null)}");
```

If you want to see what is being returned to troubleshoot use this:

```
alert("{!URLFOR($Action.Relationship__c.New,null)}");
```

Then copy and past the url and see where it takes you.

Comment: Thanks for this! The following did the trick:

Settings: 
1. Behaviour : Display in existing window without sidebar and header
2. Content Source : URL
3. Code: {!URLFOR($Action.Relationship__c.New,null)};

Comment: @sfdcstack - YW. General practice it to accept an answer that resolves your question. This allows others with the same issue to find answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps to implement.

1. List View button
2. Behaviour : Display in existing window without sidebar and header
3. Content Source : URL
4. /a2A/e

Here 'a2A' is custom object first 3 characters of id.

Answer (score 0):

The following did the trick as per the help above. I had some issues in the code.

Settings: 
1. Behaviour : Display in existing window without sidebar and header 
2. Content Source : URL 
3. Code: {!URLFOR($Action.Relationship__c.New,null)}; –